# muscle from biopython Non-zero return code 137

Tags: biopython

I am new in the python area but I would like to use biopython to align some DNA sequences. I got a script from internet and I ran it as follows (~ is the short for my home path):

```
~$ python
Python 3.5.1 (default, Jul  3 2016, 12:57:35)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from Bio.Align.Applications import MuscleCommandline
>>> muscle_exe = r"/usr/bin/muscle"
>>> in_file = r"~/SpiderOak Hive/LAB/Lab book/Ery/Seqs/tester.fasta"
>>> out_file = "~/SpiderOak Hive/LAB/Lab book/Ery/Seqs/tester_aligned.fasta"
>>> muscle_cline = MuscleCommandline(muscle_exe, input=in_file, out=out_file)
>>> print(muscle_cline)
/usr/bin/muscle -in "~/SpiderOak Hive/LAB/Lab
book/Ery/Seqs/tester.fasta" -out "~/SpiderOak Hive/LAB/Lab
book/Ery/Seqs/tester_aligned.fasta"
```

but when lauching the application I got:

```
>>> muscle_cline()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/python3.5/lib/python3.5/site-packages/Bio/Application/__init__.py",
line 516, in __call__
    stdout_str, stderr_str)
Bio.Application.ApplicationError: Non-zero return code 137 from
'/usr/bin/muscle -in "/home/gigiux/SpiderOak Hive/LAB/Lab
book/Ery/Seqs/tester.fasta" -out "/home/gigiux/SpiderOak Hive/LAB/Lab
book/Ery/Seqs/tester_aligned.fasta"', message 'MUSCLE v3.8.31 by
Robert C. Edgar'
>>>
```

What would be the issue? I have seen on internet that it might be due to memory problems; in that case is the code OK? and how could I run large alignments?

And also: why should I use = r"path" rather than simply "path"?

Many thanks,

Luigi

Comment: The `r'path'` question is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19065115/python-windows-path-slash -- did you google before asking?

Comment: The error message clearly states that `/usr/bin/muscle` failed.  This is not a problem with your Python code, as such (though it may contain invalid assumptions).  See the `muscle` documentation to figure out why it's failing -- anyway, without access to the failing code, we have no way to tell what's right or wrong with it.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my Perl script exit with 137?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041182/why-does-my-perl-script-exit-with-137)

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to be correct, and it works with small alignments. The `137` status code might be related to an "Out Of Memory" kill like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1041182). Check the last kernel messages with the command `dmesg` looking for lines like:

```
kernel: Out of memory: Kill process 52959 (java) score 164 or sacrifice child
```