# Django session cleanup gets killed

Tags: mysql, django

I tried to cleanup my expired django sessions using `./manage.py cleanup` and after hitting enter it seems to be doing something for a few seconds and then all it returns is '`killed`'. 
I also tried running the mysql shell and navigate to that table and do '`select * from django_sessions;`' and I get kicked from the shell and back to bash with the same message: '`killed`'.
What is wrong here? How can I debug that?

Comment: manage.py cleanup locks the database for killing the old sessions. Sometimes it does not release the database locks gracefully. Try unlocking the tables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like something kills long running commands. This is usual sitation on shared hosting. If you are not the owner/administrator of this server, the answer should be given by the actual owner/administrator.

Maybe these answers will help you: [Who "Killed" my process and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726690/who-killed-my-process-and-why)

Comment: thanks, indeed:kernel: Out of memory: Kill process 6652 (python) score 568 or sacrifice child

Comment: Now I need to understand why the cleanup command is eating up all the resources.