# Process Killer identification

Tags: java, linux, jakarta-ee, linux-kernel

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Who “Killed” my process and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726690/who-killed-my-process-and-why)

One java process is running by my server.In the logs I found that my server restarts automatically ( logic is there that if the process killed, start automatically ). Here I don't know who is killing my java process.May be some script, or anything...not idea about it.

Is there any way to find out who is the process killer.

I am working on Linux machine.

Comment: Have you tried asking this at [unix.stackexchange.com](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726690/who-killed-my-process-and-why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [SystemTap](http://sourceware.org/systemtap/):

```
apt-get install systemtap
```

Save this code into a **sigmon.stp** file:

```
# Track when a specific process ID receives a specific signal.  For example,
# when process ID 31994 receives a SIGKILL signal.
#
# Example command line: 
#
#   stap -x 31994 sigmon.stp SIGKILL
#
# Example output: 
#
#   SPID     SNAME            RPID  RNAME            SIGNUM SIGNAME
#   5609     bash             31994 find             9      SIGKILL 
#

probe begin
{
  printf("%-8s %-16s %-5s %-16s %6s %-16s\n",
         "SPID", "SNAME", "RPID", "RNAME", "SIGNUM", "SIGNAME")
}

probe signal.send 
{
  if (sig_name == @1 && sig_pid == target())
    printf("%-8d %-16s %-5d %-16s %-6d %-16s\n", 
      pid(), execname(), sig_pid, pid_name, sig, sig_name)
}
```