# Laravel sail artisan test is getting killed

Tags: laravel, phpunit

I am trying to run a test using `sail artisan test --filter=RestaurantAuthTest --verbose`, the process is getting killed and I don't know why, I am getting the error below. I am using Laravel Sail on WSL; I am using PHP 8.0.7 and Laravel 8.40.. I haven't had much luck finding related issues online.

```
  ⨯ restaurant auth

  ---

  • Tests\Feature\RestaurantAuthTest > restaurant auth
   PHPUnit\Framework\Exception

  Killed

  at vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/AbstractPhpProcess.php:270
    266▕
    267▕         if (!empty($stderr)) {
    268▕             $result->addError(
    269▕                 $test,
  ➜ 270▕                 new Exception(trim($stderr)),
    271▕                 $time
    272▕             );
    273▕         } else {
    274▕             set_error_handler(

  1   vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Util/PHP/AbstractPhpProcess.php:187
      PHPUnit\Util\PHP\AbstractPhpProcess::processChildResult()

  2   vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestCase.php:883
      PHPUnit\Util\PHP\AbstractPhpProcess::runTestJob()

  3   vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php:677
      PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase::run()

  4   vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php:677
      PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite::run()

  5   vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/Framework/TestSuite.php:677
      PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite::run()

  6   vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/TestRunner.php:667
      PHPUnit\Framework\TestSuite::run()

  7   vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php:143
      PHPUnit\TextUI\TestRunner::run()

  8   vendor/phpunit/phpunit/src/TextUI/Command.php:96
      PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::run()

  9   vendor/phpunit/phpunit/phpunit:61
      PHPUnit\TextUI\Command::main()


  Tests:  1 failed
  Time:   395.42s
```

Thanks

Comment: This is [Unix error message “Killed”](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16951405/367456) - As this was on stderr, I guess that's it. Talk to theirs system administrator (any gender) they should be able to help them.

Comment: Why not just to run `sail test <path-to-your-test>` ?

Comment: @Askar I will try that. Thanks