# Difference between egrep and grep

Tags: regex, grep

I have a question about `grep` and `egrep` in `unix`.

As I am recently studying the `shell commands` in `unix`, I want to know what are the differences between grep and egrep.

I find we can use grep and egrep with regular expression. However, I found something different between these two commands:

For `^`, grep and egrep have the same meaning which is finding the lines contain the given stuffs at the very beginning.

However, for `|`, grep, without back slash in front of `|`, means character of `|`, and if I put a back slash in front of it, it turns on it special meaning of finding the line contains either the stuff in front of it and behind it. BUT, for egrep, it is the opposite. `|` has the latter meanings of grep and `\|` has the former meaning of grep when uses it.

Could somebody else kindly explain why?

Comment: Closely related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45461653/why-these-variants-of-egrep-fgrep-and-rgrep-are-deprecated

Answer (score 131):

The `egrep` command is a shortcut for the `grep` binary, but with one exception: when `grep` is invoked as `egrep`, the `grep` binary activates its internal logic to run as if it were called as `grep -E`.

The difference is that `-E` option enables usage of extended regexp patterns. This allows use of meta-symbols such as `+`, `?` or `|`. These aren't ordinary characters like we may use in words or filenames but are control commands for the `grep` binary itself. Thus, with `egrep`, the character `|` means logical OR.

So, for example, you want to list files in a directory and see only those which contain "mp4" or "avi" as filename extensions. With `egrep` you will do:

`ls | egrep "mp4|avi"`

In this example `|` acts like an OR command. It will grab to output from `ls` all names which contain either "mp4" or "avi" strings. If you run it with a plain `grep` command you will get nothing, because `grep` doesn't know such thing as `|` command. Instead, `grep` will search for "mp4|avi" as a whole text string (with *pipe* symbol). E.g. if you have a file named `|mp4|avi|cool-guy.q2.stats` in your dir, you will get it with plain `grep` searching with pipes.

So, that is why you should escape `|` in your `egrep` command to achieve the same effect as in `grep`. Escaping will screen off the special meaning of `|` command for `grep` binary.

Comment: Hi rook, thank you very much. It is very clear. I really really appreciate it.

Comment: Nice explanation. Only thing I would add is that basic regular expressions *do* recognize meta-symbols such as '+', '?', '|', etc, but you have to escape them (prefix '\') to turn them on (whereas with extended regular expressions, you have to escape them to turn them off.) So "grep -E 'a|b'" is the same as "grep 'a\|b'" (matches a or b), and "grep -E 'a\|b'" is the same as "grep 'a|b'" (matches only the string 'a|b')

Comment: In `egrep`, `?`, `+` `{` `|` `(` `)` are regular expression symbols.

Comment: To complicate things a litte bit more, grep understands PCRE simbols like \d which is equivalent to [0-9], but egrep, which is supossed to be more comprehensive, doesn't.

Comment: Which symbols are recognized in both grep and egrep ? *, . ?

Answer (score 15):

Extracted from [grep explained](https://cognitivewaves.wordpress.com/grep/) and `man` pages.

`grep` provides matcher selection options.
`-E` Interpret pattern as an Extended Regular Expression (ERE)
`-G` Interpret  pattern  as a Basic Regular Expression (BRE).  This is the *default* when no option is specified.

The variant program `egrep` is  the  same  as `grep -E`. The variant is deprecated, but is provided for backward compatibility.

Therefore,
`grep` implies `grep -G`
`egrep` implies `grep -E`

There are two interpretations of the syntax in regex patterns. The difference is in the behavior of a few special characters, `?`, `+`, `()`, `{}`, and `|`.

- BRE (Basic Regular Expression) – these characters *do not* have special meaning *unless* prefixed with a backslash `\`.
- ERE (Extended Regular Expression) – these characters *are* special, *unless* prefixed with a backslash `\`.

Since `^` has the same interpretation by `grep`(BRE) and `egrep`(ERE) it works the same in both.
However, `|` is one of those characters which are interpreted differently by `grep`(BRE) and `egrep`(ERE) so it requires to be escaped with a `\` depending on the regex intent.

Answer (score 2):

The difference between grep and egrep is:

**grep**

- It uses Basic Regular Expression which means if you use `grep 'a|b'` it will not not use this "|" as OR operator without using this "\" prefix.
- It searches  for PATTERN in each FILE.

**egrep**

- It uses Extended Regular Expression and in this you can use commands like this `egrep 'a|b'`
- It treats meta-character as it is and does not substitute them as strings like grep.

Answer (score 2):

While reading through this page and a few others yields an answer, I thought I'd offer my own take. There's a TL;DR at the bottom.

First, `egrep` is a shortcut for `grep -E` and `fgrep` is a short for `grep -F`. Thus, there are three variants, and I'll discuss them.

```
 fgrep string [list of files]
 grep -F string [list of files]
```

In this variant, string is not a regular expression. It's just a string. There are no special characters. If you want to search for the filename foo.c,  you can use `grep -F foo.c` just like this, and it will work as expected. This is thus the simplest form of grep.

```
grep string [list of files]
```

In this form, your string is a basic regular expression. Only certain characters are used with their regular expression meaning, and others must be escaped with a backslant.

Let's make a simple example file:

```
File name: foo.c
File name: foo.C
foocc
```

Then I'll run grep twice:

```
$ grep 'foo.c' foo
File name: foo.c
foocc

$ grep 'foo\.c' foo
File name: foo.c
```

In the first example, the dot character is considered a meta character, and thus it matched both the dot in `foo.c` as well as the first `c` in `foocc`.

In the second example, I escaped the dot character, erasing its regular expression usage, and thus it only matched a literal dot.

I'll come back to that. Now let's look at egrep.

```
egrep string [list of files]
grep -E string [list of files]
```

In this example, string is now an Extended Regular Expression. It otherwise works the same.

So what's the difference? Well, this is in the man page:

> In basic regular expressions the meta-characters ?, +, {, |, (, and )
> lose their special meaning; instead use the backslashed versions ?,
> +, {, |, (, and ).

What does this all mean? Using either `grep` or `grep -E` or `egrep`, you can do the exact same searching. The difference is what happens when you escape characters.

In BRE (basic regular expressions), the characters in that list lose special meaning unless you escape them. In ERE (extended regular expressions), you have to escape them if you don't want their special meanings.

So, these three commands are all equivalent:

```
 grep    '\(hello\|goodbye) cruel world+'
 egrep   '(hello|goodbye) cruel world\+'
 grep -E '(hello|goodbye) cruel world\+'
```

In the first example, the parens and pipe characters are escaped, so they become meta characters. That is, we'll match either hello or goodbye. And the plus is not escaped, so it is taken literally (it's in the special list from above).

The last two examples are identical. The parents and pipe characters are not escaped, so they remain meta characters. The plus sign is escaped, so it becomes a literal.

So we'll only match lines that have a literal plus character after world. We'll match these:

```
hello cruel world+
goodbye cruel world+
```

We will not match anything else.

**So to recap**... The difference between `grep` and `grep -E` is which list of characters you escape for what, and that's it. BREs have a very short list of characters that are meta by default. EREs have a longer list. Regardless of which format you use, you can swap the meaning of a special character by escaping it.

One point of opinion: I prefer EREs. I don't have to think about which characters are which. I just use regular expressions and escape special characters if I need them as literals.

Answer (score 1):

grep command is used to find the lines having required patran in a file,we have separate meta-characters by placing '\'

egrep is equal to grep -E,which is extended regular expression uses {,},(,),|,? as meta-characters without giving '\' in expression

fgrep is used to find  the fixed string ,which is equal to grep -F

test.txt 
file
tile
(f|t)ile
(\f\|\t)ile

grep "(f|t)ile" test.txt
(f|t)ile

grep "(\f\|\t)ile" test.txt
file
tile

egrep "(f|t)ile" test.txt
file
tile

egrep "(\f\|\t)ile" test.txt
(f|t)ile

fgrep "(f|t)ile" test.txt
(f|t)ile

fgrep "(\f\|\t)ile" test.txt 
(\f\|\t)ile

Answer (score 0):

Update 2022: [ap-osd](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3209308/ap-osd)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61619511/6309) mentioned

> The variant program `egrep` is the same as `grep -E`. The variant is deprecated, but is provided for backward compatibility.

This might not be true for much longer.

This is seen in Git 2.39 (Q4 2022), which replaces GNU `[ef]grep` since GNU throws warning of their uses.

See [commit 37eb90f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/37eb90f79a97cfeb216c7afe7bb0f129edfc10e4), [commit 81580fa](https://github.com/git/git/commit/81580fa06d85ef519a46b0b225cebfe71c168a37), [commit a764c37](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a764c37bad6b4da2b248c30af1c251110fe1e031), [commit 2e09272](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2e092725e6f73d20080c3a71c0d8e234f266cb8d) (21 Sep 2022) by [Đoàn Trần Công Danh (`sgn`)](https://github.com/sgn).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit de73968](https://github.com/git/git/commit/de73968e521b5029de731bcaeef4bed0af868839), 07 Oct 2022)</sup>

> ### [`37eb90f79a`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/37eb90f79a97cfeb216c7afe7bb0f129edfc10e4):`t`: convert `fgrep` usage to "`grep -F`"
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Đoàn Trần Công Danh</sup>

> Despite POSIX states that:
>
> > The old `egrep` and `fgrep` commands are likely to be supported for many years to come as implementation extensions, allowing historical applications to operate unmodified.
>
> GNU grep 3.8 started to warn:
>
> ```
> The egrep and fgrep commands, which have been deprecated since 
> release 2.5.3 (2007), now warn that they are obsolescent 
> and should be replaced by grep -E and grep -F.
> ```
>
> **Prepare for their removal in the future**.

This refers to the [Oct. 2022 `grep` 3.8 release](https://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/info-gnu/2022-09/msg00001.html), and [commit a951562](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=grep.git;a=commit;h=a9515624709865d480e3142fd959bccd1c9372d1), which includes the FAQ:

> ### What happened to `egrep` and `grep`?
>
> 7th Edition Unix had commands `egrep` and `fgrep`
> that were the counterparts of the modern `grep -E` and `grep -F`.
>
> Although breaking up `grep` into three programs was perhaps
> useful on the small computers of the 1970s, `egrep` and
> `fgrep` were not standardized by POSIX and are no longer needed.
>
> In the current GNU implementation, `egrep` and `fgrep`
> issue a warning and then act like their modern counterparts;
> eventually, they are planned to be removed entirely.
>
> If you prefer the old names, you can use use your own substitutes,
> such as a shell script named `egrep` with the following
> contents:
>
> ```bash
> #!/bin/sh
> exec grep -E "$@@"
> ```

---

Of interest, the same Git 2.39 (Q4 2022) has an interesting (Perl) script to detect non-portable GNU script:

See [commit 2b52163](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2b521630f93b79fc8cbe0fd63fb22879a11b5024) (22 Sep 2022) by [Eric Sunshine (`sunshineco`)](https://github.com/sunshineco).
See [commit 75fc96d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/75fc96d57e1262fe4b6bf87b5887e9103bcca7fb) (23 Sep 2022) by [Junio C Hamano (`gitster`)](https://github.com/gitster).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 1f1f375](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1f1f375cfe5540c685433485bdd76552549839be), 07 Oct 2022)</sup>

> ### [`check-non-portable-shell`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2b521630f93b79fc8cbe0fd63fb22879a11b5024): detect obsolescent egrep/fgrep
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Eric Sunshine</sup>

See [`t/check-non-portable-shell.pl`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/2b521630f93b79fc8cbe0fd63fb22879a11b5024/t/check-non-portable-shell.pl#L48)

```perl
/\b[ef]grep\b/ and err 'egrep/fgrep obsolescent (use grep -E/-F)';
```