# Setuptools "development" Requirements

Tags: python, setuptools, requirements

**TL;DR**: Is there a way to hook setuptool's 'develop' to install a set of development requirements when running `python setup.py develop`?

I'm building my first python package using setuptools. I'm specifying the requirements as:

```
requirements = [
    'click',
    'ansible',
    'fabric',
    'gitpython',
    'pyyaml',
    'jinja2',
    'yapsy'
]

test_requirements = [
    'pytest',
    'pytest-pep8',
    'pytest-cov',
]

setup(
...
    install_requires=requirements,
    tests_require=test_requirements,
...
)
```

During development, I've been installing the package (in a virtual environment) with:

```
python setup.py develop
```

and uninstalling with:

```
python setup.py develop -u
```

The package uses entry_points to install some command line scripts, so this sets up the commands for me and allows me to edit the package while testing the command at the same time.

I also have some dependencies that I use for development ... sphinx + extensions and a couple other things (things that aren't needed to use the package). I'm just manually installing them in the virtual environment at the moment. I didn't see any documentation (and haven't found any examples on the googles) about how to wire them in with setuptools.

Maybe there's a way to hook 'setup.py develop' to install an additional set of requirements? Another method I haven't read about?

Comment: For development purposes I would recommend using a `requirements.txt` to pin package versions for a development environment, then run `pip install -r requirements.txt` to deploy that environment.  That's the kind of use case it's there for.

Comment: It would be really nice if setup.py had a `develop_requires` entry...

Comment: There seems to be a move towards a new pyproject.toml, but it is super hard to find information about that. Google consistently and stubbornly gives me information about setup.py. I don't want both setup.py and pyproject.toml. I'll rather give up on Python.

Answer (score 156):

For more info on using `setup.py` vs `requirements.txt`, I found [this article](https://caremad.io/2013/07/setup-vs-requirement/) helpful.

## Update: September 2016

I no longer use `requirements.txt` (see original answer below) for installing development only packages. The prevailing wisdom seems to be that `requirements.txt` should be used to pin deployments to specific version numbers, typically using `pip freeze > requirements.txt`. This ensures that the exact same versions of your project's dependencies and also your project's dependencies' dependencies are installed on all of your servers.

I instead use the `extras_require` option to `setup`.

```
requirements = [
    'click',
    'ansible',
    'fabric',
    'gitpython',
    'pyyaml',
    'jinja2',
    'yapsy'
]

setup({
    install_requires=requirements,
    extras_require={
        'dev': [
            'pytest',
            'pytest-pep8',
            'pytest-cov'
        ]
    }
})
```

Now, to install your package for development, you run `pip install -e .[dev]`. This installs all the regular required packages **and** those listed in the `dev` section of `extras_require`.

Production installs can still be done with `python setup.py install` or `pip install .` (or with a `requirements.txt` file).

## Original Answer

Here is *a* way to do it that seems to be in keeping with the recommendations I've run into regarding `setup.py` vs `requirements.txt`. Specify all your production dependencies in the `install_requires` parameter of `setup.py`.

```
requirements = [
    'click',
    'ansible',
    'fabric',
    'gitpython',
    'pyyaml',
    'jinja2',
    'yapsy'
]

setup({
    # ...
    install_requires=requirements
    # ...
})
```

Then create a `requirements.txt` file that instructs pip to install your production dependencies from `setup.py` as well as your testing dependencies.

```
-e .

pytest
pytest-pep8
pytest-cov
```

Now you can install your package for development with `pip install -r requirements.txt`. The `-e .` line will install your package and its dependencies from `setup.py` in development mode. To install on production, you could use `python setup.py install` or `pip install .`. This will only install the dependencies listed in `setup.py`.

Comment: This would probably confuse Heroku-like deployments, though, as they use `requirements.txt` for production requirements.

Comment: I keep my development requirements in a file named `Development` -- there is no reason it has to be called `requirements.txt` if that confuses a host.

Comment: Downside: extra_require leaks to your clients. It is suggesting that you have an optional feature that can be enabled by doing `pip install yourmodule[dev]`.