# How Python package should specify what needs to be installed to work on it (not to run it)? For example pylint

Tags: python, pip, packaging

I want to specify development only requirements. Specifying them with all other requirements seems suboptimal, normal users will not need it.

I see ([1](https://github.com/sentinel-hub/eo-learn/blob/master/setup.py#L45) [2](https://github.com/sentinel-hub/eo-learn/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md#development-environment)) that one of options is to have file in requirements.txt format and to instruct people to install it with command like `pip install -r requirements-dev.txt -r requirements-docs.txt`

Is this a preferred solution?

Comment: Have you seen [Setuptools development requirements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28509965/setuptools-development-requirements)?

Comment: @MatsLindh No, and searching failed to find it. I guess that I produced duplicate, thanks for locating it.

Comment: Somewhat of a duplicate question indeed. Note that some tooling help with that. A pattern I often see (and that I use) is to combine [_tox_](https://pypi.org/project/tox/) with an extra: specify a _development_ tox environment that is set to be populated with the `dev` extra. But you could also use [_poetry_ and its `dev-dependencies`](https://pypi.org/project/poetry/), there is alo [_pdm_](https://pypi.org/project/pdm/), and more...