# Why these variants of "egrep, fgrep, and rgrep" are deprecated?

Tags: unix, grep

The description of *grep, egrep, fgrep, rgrep, pgrep* are shown as below:

> DESCRIPTION
>
> grep, egrep, fgrep, rgrep, pgrep - are commands in Unix-like operating
>   systems that print lines matching a pattern. The grep searches the
>   named input FILEs for lines containing a match to the given PATTERN.
>   By default, it prints the matching lines.
>
> In addition, the variant programs egrep, fgrep, and rgrep are the same
>   as grep -E, grep -F, and grep -r, respectively. These variants are
>   deprecated, but are provided for backward compatibility.

Why these variants of **egrep, fgrep, and rgrep** are deprecated?

Comment: Voting to close as **primarily opinion based** "Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise." . Please read  http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask , http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask ,  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve  and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) before posting more Qs here. Good luck.

Comment: seeing [Why is direct invocation as either egrep or fgrep deprecated?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/383448/why-is-direct-invocation-as-either-egrep-or-fgrep-deprecated/383454#383454)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's answered in the *[Rationale](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/grep.html)* for the POSIX description of grep:

> This grep has been enhanced in an upwards-compatible way to provide the exact functionality of the historical egrep and fgrep commands as well. *It was the clear intention of the standard developers to consolidate the three greps into a single command*.
>
> The old egrep and fgrep commands are likely to be supported for many years to come as implementation extensions, allowing historical applications to operate unmodified.
>
> Historical implementations usually silently ignored all but one of multiply-specified -e and -f options, but were not consistent as to which specification was actually used.