# Linux ps aux with grep check for specific PHP process ID

Tags: linux, grep

I'm trying to figure out whether a PHP process is running or not using the `ps aux` command and passing `grep` to it, for instance:

I need it to return and tell me whether a process ID on php is running or not but whenever I try the following I always seem to get a result where the result is appending `1234` at the end, what am I missing?

```
ps aux | grep 'php|1234'
```

[image]

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/74185/how-can-i-prevent-grep-from-showing-up-in-ps-results

Comment: You can exclude the grep with `grep 'grep' -v`. How do you know it will always have that id? e.g. `ps aux | grep 'php|1234' | grep 'grep' -v` should work. I would search for the file name rather than a process id.

Comment: If you're looking for specific process ID attached, you're going to have to chain 2 greps, I think. `grep` will look for that specific string, while `egrep` will look for lines that have *either* `php` or the number you're passing in.  See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18058875/difference-between-egrep-and-grep

Answer (score 0):

Suggesting `pgrep` command instead of `ps aux`

```
pgrep -af "php"
```

The reason your get always one line:

1. `php` process is not matched with `grep 'php|123123123'`
2. `ps aux` list the `grep` command you submitted and the `grep` command match itself
3. maybe you meant `grep -E 'php|123123123'` to match `php` or `123123123`

Answer (score 0):

The solution I've come across thanks to a user above is to do:

```
ps aux | grep '123456' | grep 'grep' -v
```

Where **123456** would be the process ID