# How to know the reason why the process was killed by system(linux)

Tags: linux

I run the python program which is a server that receive data from client; But after few minutes, the process was killed by system; How can I know the real reason ?

Comment: This could be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726690/who-killed-my-process-and-why?rq=1

Comment: did the process terminate? or was it killed?how did you verify?

Comment: How do you handle requests? Do you start threads or subprocesses?

Comment: Is your server on linux? Have you look at `/var/log/kern.log`?

Answer (score 1):

The exact log file varies dependingon distribution and configuration, but if you do
`ls -ldrat /var/log/*` it will show the most recently edited logfiles at the bottom. The files `messages`,`dmesg` and `daemon` are all likely sources of information.

Possible reasons are:

- memory exception (i.e. segfault)
- process limits breach (to many File descriptors or processes being opened) - check `/etc/security/limits.conf` and surrounding files
- SElinux (if enabled) - that should have been logged to messages.