# What does unit test killed mean?

Tags: java, unit-testing, jenkins

My app's jenkins build failed due to one unit test is killed as following, and unfortunately I can not log into the jenkins server to see the detail logs, could anyone tell me what does this "killed" mean?

```
Running com.myapp.test.TestMyClass
Killed
```

Comment: Please post the process limits from `ulimit -a` for the user that Jenkins is running as.

Answer (score 0):

Could it be that you are running a memory-intensive unit test e.g. on Linux and the [out-of-memory killer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/726690/60462) came around and killed the underlying Java process? What happens if you run the test from the command line yourself?

Comment: It runs normally in my local box, but sometimes killed on the jenkins server.