# AWS EBS Deploy: Update environment operation is complete, but with errors. For more information, see troubleshooting documentation

Tags: amazon-web-services, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I've been dealing with this issue since yesterday. All working until 4 PM and suddenly after that this error keeps coming.

```
Creating application version archive "882a".
Uploading: [##################################################] 100% Done...
INFO: Environment update is starting.                               
INFO: Deploying new version to instance(s).                         
INFO: Command execution completed on all instances successfully.    
INFO: New application version was deployed to running EC2 instances.
ERROR: Update environment operation is complete, but with errors. For more information, see troubleshooting documentation.

ERROR: Update environment operation is complete, but with errors. For more information, see troubleshooting documentation.
```

No logs has been logged after that. Even there are no logs coming in AWS management console. I ssh the instance and checked all the logs `/var/log/`, they all have logs only until 4 PM.

So this is possibly a dead end I'm stuck with. I tried rebuilding the environment but no luck. The [forum](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=156252&start=25&tstart=0) discusses this, but all troubleshooting is happening behind the screens, no possible solutions provided.

Any idea on how to resolve this?

Comment: Which region is this in? 4PM what time zone? Also are you saying you issue update environment and you see no logs under /var/log? Can you post the last few lines of /var/log/eb-activity.log?

Comment: It is EU West. I tried rebuilding the environment and tried with the new RDS from snapshot. It took about hours to rebuild environment and finally the site was up..

Comment: For someone reading this: 

Possible things: Auto Scaling deleted your older instance, that is why you only have logs till 4PM. Try termination protection on the auto scaling group or at individual ec2 instance.