# How to fix a broken stream/dead verify?

Tags: mercurial

I've just tried to clone a repo but got this:

```
$ hg clone ssh://path/to/repo              
destination directory: assessment
requesting all changes
adding changesets
adding manifests
adding file changes
transaction abort!
rollback completed
abort: stream ended unexpectedly (got 531348 bytes, expected 534446)
```

I tried verifying the repo on the server:

```
$ hg verify
checking changesets
checking manifests
crosschecking files in changesets and manifests
checking files
Killed
```

What the heck does "killed" mean?? How do I fix that?

Comment: Maybe related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/726690/65387

Comment: What happens if you run `hg --debug verify` on the server?  Grepping through the codebase I don't see `Killed` with a capital `K` anywhere, suggesting that output is coming from somewhere deeper in Python.

Comment: @dimo414 I found it. It wasn't Hg or Python at all. It was the linux kernal. Hurray for generic error messages :D Could have told me I was out of memory so it had to kill it, but no, just "killed".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server ran out of memory and didn't have any swap so linux killed it. Apparently Mercurial consumes a fair bit of memory.