# SpringBoot app stops after a hour.

Tags: linux, tomcat, spring-boot, java-7

I have a Spring Boot app (1.2.6) running on Oracle Linux with Tomcat embedded.  Using java 1.7.0_45.  It will run fine for 20 minutes to 2 hours.  Then something either kills it or it self-destructs.  I have a poor man's monitor to tell when it dies.  Nothing useful appears in the application logback log file, other than a failure to release jdbc resources.  Can I do anything to get Spring or Tomcat to tell me why it is stopping?  Could a shutdown hook tell me why the java process is being terminated?  I'm not using Spring Boot Actuator yet.  What tools on linux could log a history of activity for a specific pid?

Comment: It could be Linux's out of memory killer. If it is, this question may be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726690/who-killed-my-process-and-why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try enabling Oracle's black box technology.

```
$JAVA_HOME/bin/java -XX:+UnlockCommercialFeatures -XX:+FlightRecorder -XX:FlightRecorderOptions=dumponexit=true,defaultrecording=true,dumponexitpath=/tmp/crash-data.jfr -jar my.jar
```

Obviously, you have to be running Oracle's JDK.

Comment: So it died shortly after I exited my terminal session.  The jfr file showed a SIGHUP event near the end.  I guess using an ampersand on the end of the command line does not do what I expected.  I'm still waiting for it to die again.  When I restart it again, I'll try the "nohup" command.  Memory usage seems to be stable at 64 MB.  I doubt I have the liberty to create a service or add it to _init.d_, but I'll explore that option more later.

Answer (score 1):

You likely want to use something like:

- [visualvm](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/) for monitoring the running JVM, or
- [jstack](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jstack.html) + [jhat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/share/jhat.html) for analyzing the stack and heap at termination.

To get a heap dump at JVM shutdown (assuming it dies on OutOfMemoryError), add this to your JVM options:

```
-XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError
```