# Running translate on ipython kills the process

Tags: tensorflow

I am running the translate demo on ipython using:

```sh
>> %run translate.py --data_dir data --train_dir data --max_train_data_size 100000
```

The process gets killed automatically for some reason. Here is the output of the run.

```sh
Preparing WMT data in data/
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/local_device.cc:25] Local device intra op parallelism threads: 3
I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/local_session.cc:45] Local session inter op parallelism threads: 3
Creating 3 layers of 1024 units.
Created model with fresh parameters.
Reading development and training data (limit: 100000).
    reading data line 100000
Killed
```

I am running it on a vagrant box running  Ubuntu 14.04 and no gpu. What might be happening here?

Comment: Does it work when you run translate.py it from the command line?

Answer (score 1):

That's not ipython/tensorflow specific.

Kills like that can come from the linux kernel if it decides, basically, that a process is using too much memory.

[Who "Killed" my process and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726690/who-killed-my-process-and-why)