# python interpreter killed when loading spacy

Tags: python, conda, spacy

Problem:
Python interpreter is killed when running the following lines of code:

```
from spacy.en import English
nlp = English()
```

The example is at the following link:
https://spacy.io/#example-use

Environment:

- MacBook
- Conda (I've installed spacy via conda) with python 3.5

The error I receive is simply the word "killed" and it exits out of the python interpreter.

Has anyone run into this error before?

-thanks

Answer (score 0):

The message "killed" in this case probably indicates that your kernel shut down the process because it was starved for resources (see [Who "Killed" my process and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726690/who-killed-my-process-and-why))