# Spark application getting killed abruptly

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I'm trying to implement power iteration clustering in spark. I'm running it from spark shell , the shell is exiting abruptly with the following error message

```
/opt/spark/spark-1.4.1-bin-hadoop2.6/bin/spark-shell: line 54: 30324 Killed
     "$FWDIR"/bin/spark-submit --class org.apache.spark.repl.Main "$@"
```

Any reason for the behavior

Comment: Sounds like the OS has killed the process, perhaps due to lack of memory - see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726690/who-killed-my-process-and-why

Comment: could it be because of high cpu consumtion?

Comment: We're going to need more details to have any chance of working out what's wrong.

Comment: Did you solve it?