# Why I get message Killed in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x

When I run Python script after I get message `Killed`. What does it mean?

I tried to find logs, but they are empty

Comment: sharing your script would actually help in answering the question of why the script is killed.

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726690/who-killed-my-process-and-why

Comment: @MisterPi - share your code so we can recognized why you are facing this issue.

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What does it mean?

**answer -**

Your script crossed some limit in the amount of system resources that you are allowed to use. Depending on your OS and configuration, this could mean you had too many open files, used too much filesytem space or something else.

Answer (score 1):

If you did not kill the Python process, then it is most likely that the system ran out of some resource, and then the OS will kill it.