# Mallet topic modelling issue when training with large number of topics

Tags: topic-modeling, mallet

I am trying to build a topic model with 10000 topics on a dataset of 1M samples. After data is loaded I am getting this line:

`bin/mallet: line 62: 17428 Killed                  $JAVA_COMMAND $CLASS $*`.

This is the command I am running:

```
`bin/mallet train-topics \
  --input data.mallet \
  --output-model topics.model \
  --output-topic-keys topic-keys.txt \ 
  --topic-word-weights-file topic-word-weights.txt \
  --word-topic-counts-file word-topic-counts-file.txt \
  --output-doc-topics doc-topics.txt \
  --num-topics 10000 \
  --num-threads 28 \
  --num-iterations 2000 \
  --use-symmetric-alpha FALSE`
```

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: This looks like a memory problem, you might check [this question about memory allocation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/726690/who-killed-my-process-and-why).

Comment: @DavidMimno Thank you. I had my suspicions on that. I am using 200G of memory and it works for 1000 topics but when I increase to 5K or 10K it kills the process. Does the number of threads affect the memory allocation requirements?

Comment: Yes, each thread builds its own copy of the type-topic counts. Threads may actually have more effect than number of topics.

Comment: @DavidMimno Thank you very much. This is a very helpful advice. I will try building a model with lower number of threads and see if I can keep it within the memory boundaries.