# Why phantomjs script is killed automatically in between script execution?

Tags: phantomjs

I am trying to do web scraping using phantomJs. I am doing recurring task in that script so same script runs around 10k times with different parameters in single execution. It would take around 3 hours to complete process.

The issue is, it suddenly stops at random point with **killed** status written on the screen.

I tried some of the tricks to solve it but nothing worked.
 Like - Tried localStorage.clear() in page.evaluate() function,
  Reinstalling Phantom Js

So I need to know why it is happening and what can I do to fix it.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/726762/2715393

Comment: What do you run it on - VPS? dedicated server? shared hosting?

Comment: Thanks...It worked. Issue was coming because of swap exhaustion.
When I increased my swap memory size, it started working.