# Running Rails Console Gets Killed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, linux, ruby-on-rails-4, centos

When i run on my production servers the command:

```
bundle exec rails c production
```

After few seconds i get "Killed", the server has 32GB RAM and have no lack of memory.

I use Ruby 2.1.6 with Rails 4.2.9 On CentOS 6.5.

I tried add SWAP file it doesn't worked.

Comment: Is there any stacktrace? In stdout or log/production.log ?

Comment: No there is nothing on both of them.

Comment: Can you check if there is any log in `/var/log/kern.log`?

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726690/who-killed-my-process-and-why) may help you.

Comment: Is there a renegade `cron` job calling `killall ruby`? Does this happen with any Ruby process or just your `rails c`? Using a tool like `top` or `htop` do you see memory get exhausted? An infinite loop allocating memory in your initializers could cause this.