# Elastic Search does not start

Tags: java, elasticsearch, search, lucene

When I start elastic search, I see "Killed" on the console and the process ends. I am unable to get the elastic search process to start. What am I missing?

```
:~/elasticsearch-5.5.2/bin$ ./elasticsearch
Killed
```

If it is relevant, I am installing this on a VPS. I don't see any other error message - making it hard to debug.

Comment: Maybe check the memory settings?

Comment: @Mena - where can I check that? Also, what am I looking for? I just got started using elastic - hence the questions.. thanks.

Comment: Not particularly knowledgeable myself, but try and look at the heap settings somewhere around `/etc/sysconfig/elasticsearch`?

Comment: You can check `dmesg` after it's killed, to confirm that it was killed for memory use (this is very, very likely the case). If that's the issue try updating jvm.options (probably `elasticsearch-5.5.2/config/jvm.options`?) to limit to about half the memory your VPS has (update both the `Xms` and `Xmx` to the same number -- err on the lower side, not the higher side).

Comment: Yes, it is running out of memory:

Out of memory in UB 5315: OOM killed process 25169 (nginx) score 0 vm:86176kB, rss:880kB, swap:724kB
Out of memory in UB 5315: OOM killed process 25169 (nginx) score 0 vm:86176kB, rss:880kB, swap:724kB
[18842961.861257] Out of memory in UB 5315: OOM killed process 25227 (java) score 0 vm:2925476kB, rss:847800kB, swap:0kB

Answer (score 8):

### As of configuring RAM usage by Elasticsearch

- Find the elasticsearch `jvm.options` file location, by default it is [/etc/elasticsearch/jvm.options](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/setting-system-settings.html#jvm-options)
- Set the -Xms and -Xmx options in there to reflect the RAM amout available at your VPS as [described here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/heap-size.html)

By default, elasticsearch tries to occupy 1Gb of RAM at start, so **if your VPS has less than 1Gb of RAM** you need to configure elasticsearch to use less RAM accordingly

As an alternative to above file configuration you can try export of [corresponding environment variable](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/heap-sizing.html)

> export ES_JAVA_OPTS="-Xms256m -Xmx256m"

and then check if it helps

> ./elasticsearch

### Regarding the exit state

> Killed

It [most frequently](https://stackoverflow.com/a/726762/8513835) indicates the [OoM Killer](https://linux-mm.org/OOM_Killer) process activity which is aimed on emergent RAM freeing to let Linux survive the lack of available RAM event. OoM Killer, as per his name, sends kill signal to some most memory-consuming user process.

As of VPS and it's virtualization model, there are some custom container-based OoM settings in effect (check out [example for OpenVZ](https://docs.openvz.org/openvz_users_guide.webhelp/_configuring_container_oom_killer_behavior.html)), so if you're 100% sure you're configured ealsticsearch correctly, and there is enough RAM to start its instance - contact your VPS provider to clarify possible limits (like 10% of RAM must always be free or OoM Killer is triggered otherwise)

Some debug approach to OoM Killer events is [described in this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/128667)