# How to see who kills execution of the script?

Tags: linux, bash

There's a complicated script that starts other scripts. It all runs for about 6 hours. But I've noticed that one or two child scripts are being killed from time to time.

All I get is a line in log saying that script is killed.

How do I get some info on who kills it? Is it possible?

Comment: This question is for ServerFault, not for SO

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nature of killing a process does not provide an *originator*. A bit is set in a kernel structure associated with the process, indicating a signal is pending. If the signalling process does not indicate it is signalling, there's no way to find out.

Some processes do in fact announce their signalling. On Linux, the OOM (Out of Memory) killer might write a log entry to `/var/log/messages`. If the reason for the signalling to your script is an OOM condition, this might be the place to look.

See also [Who "Killed" my process and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726690/who-killed-my-process-and-why)

Comment: Thank you, very informative! Have a great day, Jens.