# How to find the root cause of Java application die in Linux

Tags: java, linux, kill

My java application running in linux always disappear every two hours, How can I find the root cause.
First I think it is killed by oom, so I change /proc//oom_adj t0 -17, doesn't work.
Second I user strace -p PID, the exit code is 1.

Comment: You may find an answer here https://stackoverflow.com/q/726690/4848659

Answer (score 0):

You can configure JMX on the application and attach JConsole or JVisualVM and monitor the heap. You can also enable garbage collection on the JVM and have it write to a file gc.log. You can view the log to see what is happening with memory on the process.

Answer (score 0):

You may be having problems with user limits or `ulimit`, recently I had a problem with java in linux to read very large files, the same problem happened, my application disappears without explanation.

For my case the solution was to modify the /etc/security/limits.conf file by adding my user to the file as follows:

```
<user> soft nofile 4096
<user> hard nofile 8192
```

In your case the solution may be different, I advise you to take a look [here](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Limits.conf) or see the [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/5/limits.conf), you can have better explanations.