# Jobs being killed for an unidentifiable reason

Tags: linux

On Linux, I try to run a fortran executable (or even recompile and then run) and the job is killed immediately. The process just says "Killed". Now, if I copy the whole directory, the program will run just fine in the "new" directory -- but never in the original. This is happening repeatedly, but not universally, and seems random to me. Even though I have a work-a-round, I am still wondering why this happens at all.

Comment: Run it with `strace` and check what the last lines are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Run your program with `strace` to find out what it is doing before it gets killed. Just speculating: But could it be allocating a huge amount of memory? If system memory is exhausted the out-of-memory killer usually kills the process that uses memory most aggressively. Check `/var/log/syslog` to see if the OOM killer was kicking in.

Also see [What killed my process and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726690/what-killed-my-process-and-why) and [Will Linux start killing my processes without asking me if memory gets short?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136291/will-linux-start-killing-my-processes-without-asking-me-if-memory-gets-short).

Comment: So, it just says "+++ killed by SIGKILL +++", however, I don't have permission to get into /var/log/syslog (this is on a cluster and I am only a user). That being said, I do think it is the memory. I'm not 100% on what to do to fix the way I allocate memory, but I do suspect that this is the problem. Thanks for your time + help!