# Handling out of memory killed signal in python

Tags: python, pandas, performance, out-of-memory

I have a python written a python module to query a database and read this into a dataframe.
Some of these queries are quite big and are causing the module to exit. i.e. I get:

```
Exited
```

printed to the screen. Digging a bit deeper, I find

```
Memory cgroup out of memory: Kill process
```

So it's running out of memory - my question is how do I capture that kill signal so I can print a useful error message e.g. you need to request more resources to run this command...
Currently I have:

```
import signal
import pandas as pd

kill_now = False
def exit_gracefully(signum, frame, ):
    kill_now = True

signal.signal(signal.SIGINT, exit_gracefully)
signal.signal(signal.SIGTERM, exit_gracefully)
sql_reader = pd.read(query, conn, chunksize=1000)
table_data = []
while not kill_now:
    for data in sql_reader:
        table_data.append(data)
    break
if kill_now:
   print("ran out of memory...")
```

But this doesn't catch the "Killed" signal

Comment: Are you sure the process being killed is python, not some spawned database driver process?

Comment: how could a check that?

Comment: Have you checked answers and links to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726690/what-killed-my-process-and-why)?

Comment: I'm not sure that helps - I don't have control over the RAM, all I can do is capture the error and give a more descriptive message to the user - i.e. that they need to increase their RAM. But I agree that that question is likely the issue i.e. process is most likely being killed OOMKiller. I'd guess I need to specify a memory limit, and exit if that is reached - that memory limit being below the actual amount of memory available - but I couldn't find a way to get the max memory available