# Terminal process get killed with code ELIFECYCLE errno: 137 when VS Code is open. Quitting VS Code resolves the issue?

Tags: npm, visual-studio-code, npm-scripts

I've only recently in the last two days begun encountering this issue.

When I attempt to build my Angular project, It's getting to this one point and failing with errors below.

The only way I can get it to run is to quit VS code and rerun the exact same command and it builds without issue.
Any ideas what may be causing this?

[image]

Comment: Note: Git is not involved in this at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`137` is 128 + 9.  In some situations—and I'm guessing that this is one of them—this indicates that the process died with a signal 9.  Signal 9 is, on macOS (and multiple other OSes), `SIGKILL`.  This signal is sent by the "out of memory" killer.

This also explains why exiting VSCode fixes things: VSCode is a memory hog.  Exiting it returns the memory to the system.

To fix this more permanently, either reduce the memory needs of your build and/or of VSCode, or add more memory to your system.

See also [What killed my process and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/726690/1256452)

Comment: Bingo! I'm on Mac OS. I disabled several extensions and after reloading the VS Code app, my terminal process now runs without being killed