# WSO2 does not start; The process is being killed

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-identity-server

I installed wso2 on linux server. When I want to run the application with the `sh wso2server.sh` command in the bin file, **"Killed"** appears on the console screen and the application does not work. I also tried with the `sh wso2server start` command. It still didn't work. There is no error when I look at the log files. What is the reason for this and how can I solve it?

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you have enough memory in the machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the Operating System is Killing your process. One reason for this is you do not have enough memory in the VM to start the Java process. So first check whether you have allocated enough memory to this VM?

If that's not the case, you should be able to find more information from the Kernal logs to determine why the process was killed. Typically located at `/var/log/kern.log` or `/var/log/dmesg`.

Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726690/what-killed-my-process-and-why) question as well.

Comment: Thanks you for asnwered. Clear my memory caches. Its work now