# Process stopped with the sole message killed

Tags: rust, println, oom

I am writing a program that prints out fibonacci numbers. When I tried to implement threading, the program will crash (normally while printing a number, not calculating the next) with the sole message `Killed`.  I have ran `dstat --top-oom` and my program never shows up (rust-analyzer sits at 754 and does not move when running the program).
Code:

```rust
use rug::Integer;
use std::sync::mpsc;
use std::thread;

struct FibSequ {
    curr: Integer,
    next: Integer
}

impl Default for FibSequ {
    fn default() -> Self {
        Self {curr: Integer::from(0), next: Integer::from(1)}
    }
}

impl Iterator for FibSequ {
    type Item = Integer;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        let current = self.curr.clone();

        self.curr = self.next.clone();
        self.next = &current + self.next.clone();
        
        Some(current)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let (tx, rx) = mpsc::channel();

    thread::spawn(move || {
        let mut fib = FibSequ::default();
        loop {
            tx.send(fib.next().unwrap()).unwrap();
        }
    });

    for i in rx {
        println!("{}", i);
    }
}
```

Bin: [Bin [md5: 07e3d09f41e1153694ef4e041c7eeb50]](https://test-bench.inyourface3445.repl.co/fib_seq.txt)
Last bit of output before it crashed:

```
...7680751160335033301153281304688311853222415855824651640807481Killed
```

Comment: Post the code of your program, otherwise it's just impossible to know what's happening. It's very likely there is a subtle bug  in your code.

Comment: That is what the rustexplorer.com link is, have you tried to click on it?

Comment: Please read: [Questions linking to external web sites instead of showing code](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/80978/questions-linking-to-external-web-sites-instead-of-showing-code). Code on external sites CAN change without notice....

Comment: The reason I didn't originally is because I did not want the body of the question to be mostly code and not be able to submit it.

Comment: Try receiving the data with rx: `rx.recv().unwrap()`

Comment: When i have tried that, both `for i in rx.recv().unwrap()` and `println!("{}", rx.recv().unwrap())` both just printed a 0 and ended without an error code.

Comment: Try: `loop{ println!("{}", rx.recv().unwrap()); }` to update rx

Comment: Related: [What killed my process and why?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726690/what-killed-my-process-and-why)

Comment: I've build and run it locally in release mode. And it seems that this program leaks memory. I don't know yet what causes it, but this seems to be the case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an *unbounded* channel, which means it is infinitely buffered. Writing the numbers to the terminal is much slower than computing new numbers, so your channel will buffer an increasing amount of numbers. The easiest way to fix this is using a *bounded* channel instead. All you need to do is replacing `mpsc::channel()` with something like `mpsc::sync_channel(10)`, allowing for a queue of ten numbers. The program will still eventually oom, but it takes way longer.

On my Ubuntu box the process gets terminated by earlyoom. Since earlyoom is sending SIGTERM, I see `Terminated` instead of `Killed`. The event is logged in the syslog:

```
128994:2023-05-23T17:36:19.036901+02:00 iona earlyoom[1375]: mem avail:  3156 of 31737 MiB ( 9.95%), swap free:    0 of  979 MiB ( 0.00%)
128995:2023-05-23T17:36:19.053830+02:00 iona earlyoom[1375]: low memory! at or below SIGTERM limits: mem 10.00%, swap 10.00%
128996:2023-05-23T17:36:19.053953+02:00 iona earlyoom[1375]: sending SIGTERM to process 1480267 uid 1000 "playground_8tiu": badness 1002, VmRSS 9899 MiB
128997:2023-05-23T17:36:19.143083+02:00 iona earlyoom[1375]: process exited after 0.1 seconds
```

Comment: Why do you say that program will eventually oom? If memory is released as quick as it allocated (sync channel forces that), then why would this be the problem?

Comment: @AleksanderKrauze The numbers are growing exponentially, so the memory needed to store a single number grows linearly. The iterator is completely unbounded, so you will eventually get to numbers that are too big to fit into memory. This may take a while, depending on how much memory you have.

Comment: Ah, I forgot about that. :) Thanks.