# Symfony 6 issue with cache clear in prod environnement

Tags: symfony, symfony6

I'm currently trying to upgrade my application from Symfony 5.4 to Symfony 6.4 but I've encountered an issue when i set my environment to "prod".

When I set the env to dev, I can clear the cache and my application can work. When I set the env to prod, the cache:clear command is instantly killed, so the cache is never warmed up and my application never accept to run.

By "instantly killed", i mean that in my terminal i see "Killed !" appear on screen. The same error seems to appear even if I pass the flag to not warming the cache.

I can't figure out where this bug comes from or how to find what is killing the script, so I'm asking for the opinion of people better than me on this type of subject.

PS : Sorry for my broken english, I'm non-english native

Comment: are you able to delete var/cache/prod? Possible permissions error

Comment: Yup, i can delete it manually, but i have the same "Killed!" when i try towarm up the cache

Comment: so try deleting manually and then cache:warmup --env=prod --no-debug

Comment: Same result, and I absoluletely don't know why

Comment: For information, i've let voluntarily an error in my services.yaml and, in this case, an error is correctly raised. The problem seems with the mounting of services, but i don't exactly know which one. And why only in "prod" mode

Comment: I would assume that the process is killed by the operating system: https://stackoverflow.com/q/726690/4275413 . if that's the case, it's really hard to figure out what part of the code kills the process. Probably not possible to debug without a debugger. However, I might be wrong, in that case search for "Killed" in your codebase to find the source ;o)

Comment: Unfortunately, i've had the same idea but no result