Program using framebuffer killed on Ubuntu 18.04 but works on Ubuntu 22.04
I'm currently developing a program that interacts with the framebuffer. The program works perfectly on Ubuntu 22.04, but it gets killed with the message "killed" on Ubuntu 18.04.
Here is the specific line of code where the program gets killed:
*(fb->fbp + location) = b;

I've tried running the program with sudo, and I've also checked the permissions of /dev/fb0. However, the problem persists.
The program works without issues on a system running kernel version 6.5.0-35-generic (Ubuntu 22.04).
The issue arises on a system with kernel version 5.4.0-150-generic (Ubuntu 18.04).
Based on my research, I suspect the issue might be due to differences in the kernel versions or framebuffer drivers between these Ubuntu versions. Here are the steps I've taken so far to diagnose the issue:

Verified and adjusted the permissions of /dev/fb0 using sudo chmod 666 /dev/fb0.

My questions are:
What could be causing the program to get killed on Ubuntu 18.04 but not on Ubuntu 22.04?
Any help or pointers would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <linux/fb.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>

#define FB_OPEN_FAIL 1
#define FB_GET_FINFO_FAIL 2
#define FB_GET_VINFO_FAIL 3
#define FB_MMAP_FAIL 4
#define DIAMETER 10
typedef unsigned char uchar;

typedef struct dev_fb_t
{
    int fbfd;
    struct fb_var_screeninfo vinfo;
    struct fb_fix_screeninfo finfo;
    long int screensize;
    char *fbp;
}dev_fb;

long int locate(dev_fb* fb, int x, int y)
{
    return (x+fb->vinfo.xoffset) * (fb->vinfo.bits_per_pixel/8) + (y+fb->vinfo.yoffset) * fb->finfo.line_length;
}

int fb_init(dev_fb* fb)
{
    fb->fbfd=0;
    fb->fbp=NULL;
    fb->fbfd=open("/dev/fb0", O_RDWR);

    if(fb->fbfd==-1)
        return FB_OPEN_FAIL;
    if(ioctl(fb->fbfd, FBIOGET_FSCREENINFO, &(fb->finfo))==-1)
        return FB_GET_FINFO_FAIL;
    if(ioctl(fb->fbfd, FBIOGET_VSCREENINFO, &(fb->vinfo))==-1)
        return FB_GET_VINFO_FAIL;

    fb->screensize=fb->vinfo.xres * fb->vinfo.yres * fb->vinfo.bits_per_pixel / 8;

    fb->fbp=(char*)mmap(0,fb->screensize, PROT_READ | PROT_WRITE, MAP_SHARED, fb->fbfd, 0);
    if(fb->fbp==MAP_FAILED) {
        fb->fbp = NULL;
        return FB_MMAP_FAIL;
    }

fprintf( stderr, "[FB] %d x %d\n", (int)fb->vinfo.xres, (int)fb->vinfo.yres );

    return 0;
}

void fb_fillScr(dev_fb* fb, char r, char g, char b)
{
    int x,y;
    long int location;
    for(y=0;y<(int)fb->vinfo.yres;y++)
    {
        for(x=0;x<(int)fb->vinfo.xres;x++)
        {
            location=locate(fb,x,y);
            *(fb->fbp+location)=b;//A kill occurred on this line.
            *(fb->fbp+location+1)=g;
            *(fb->fbp+location+2)=r;
            *(fb->fbp+location+3)=0;
        }
    }
}

int main() {
   dev_fb fb;
   fb_init(&fb);
    
   fb_fillScr(&fb, 255, 255, 255);
}



We need a [mcve]

Your program may have undefined behavior which means anything can happen including but not limited to the program giving your expected output. But never rely on a program with UB. The program may just crash.

You are probably dereferencing an incorrect pointer here. Since that is undefined behavior different compiler versions are allowed to generate different assembly code.  (the undefined behavior part).  So in a way it seemed to work on your older version and only now you see the real bug.

You're not checking for any errors from fb_init.  Are you getting a 0 back?

"Killed" (i.e. receiving SIGKILL) usually means that you have overcommit enabled and your system is out of memory; see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/726690/what-killed-my-process-and-why/726879#726879.  But in that case, the kill wouldn't be associated with a particular line of code. How did you ascertain that this line is the issue? What exact steps did you follow to run the code that resulted in the "Killed" message?

@StephenNewell Yeah I got 0 from "fb_init".

@NateEldredge I ascertained it by using GDB and running the program and then i got "Program terminated with signal SIGKILL, Killed.
The program no longer exists." this message.
To follow to run the cod, i ran the code on different Ubuntu version and it worked.

Your fb_fillScr function assumes 32 bits per pixel but your code doesn't verify that this is actually what fb->vinfo.bits_per_pixel equals.  Maybe the older Ubuntu version uses a different video mode with a different color depth?  Can you determine the value of location when the crash occurs, as well as x and y?

@NateEldredge I checked current system(Ubuntu 18.04)'s available framebuffer settings by using "fbset".
mode "800x600"
geometry 800 600 800 600 32
timings 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
accel true
rgba 8/16,8/8,8/0,0/0
endmode
This is the log before killed
[FB] 800 x 600, 32 bpp
location: 0 x: 0 y: 0
killed
